# Keep div height the same despite resizing a window

Tags: html, css, height

When I resize the window text from multiple divs overlaps onto another.
I believe it is maybe because my height values apply for percent of the screen, not percent of the div as I would like. What I would like for now (unless someone has a better idea) is instead of vertical div size decreasing have it stay fixed, therefore preventing the text from being pushed onto another div.
I've seen similar posts but none of them seemed to specifically address my issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I want the div height to stay the same despite reducing window size.

FINAL EDIT: I will deal with this issue when I finish my computer-compatible site and then work on making it mobile-compatible.

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v5aobbp3/

```
<div id="moreinfo" class="wrapperdiv">
        <div id="topquote">
            <br> <br>
            <p id="quote"> &ldquo;  Musical activity involves nearly every region of the brain that we know about, and nearly every neural subsystem &rdquo; </p> 
            <p id="quote2"> &mdash; Daniel Levitin, <em> This is Your Brain on Music, </em> p.299  </p> 
        </div>  
        <div id="benefits-main">
            <div id="top-row">
                <div id="leftfact">
                    <p class="benefits-title">  express yourself</p> <br>
                    <p id="bodytext"> Music is the best way for you to express yourself, unleash your creativity, and get inspired. Immerse yourself or your children in the world of music through musical education to produce an enhanced appreciation and understanding of this art </p>
                </div>
                <div id="centrefact">
                    <p class="benefits-title"> improved cognitive abilities </p> <br>
                    <p id="bodytext"> The auditory precision required in music study results in dramatic improvements in language abilities. Musically trained children are able to distinguish subtleties of speech, resulting in increased verbal, comprehension, reading, and communication skills. Students of music have better information processing, stronger neural connections, improved memory, and bigger brains in general.
                </div>
                <div id="rightfact">
                    <p class="benefits-title"> increased focus and academics</p>
                    <p id="bodytext"> Music gives its learners an increased attention span and stronger focus as well as self-discpline. Children who learn music have higher IQs and better motor coordination. Studies have found that music students significantly outperform academically compared to other students and are more motivated.
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-row">
                <div id="leftfact2">
                    <p class="benefits-title"> empathy and social awareness </p> <br>
                    <p id="bodytext"> Musical education increases empathy in children as well as improves their emotional intelligence and interpretation of nuances of speech. Music is emotional and through this art students learn to connect with others on an emotional level. While performing with other musicians students increase their cooperation skills. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="centrefact2">
                    <p class="benefits-title"> self-confidence </p>
                    <p id="bodytext"> Performing as well as self-discipline give students a high level of confidence </p>
                </div>
                <div id="rightfact2">
                    <div id="button2">
                        <a href="https://www.rcmusic.ca/sites/default/files/files/RCM_MusicEducationBenefits.pdf" class="rcmlink"> <p class="button2text"> Learn More </p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomquote">
            <br>
            <p id="musicquote" class="Einstein">  "The theory of relativity occurred to me by intuition, and music is the driving force behind this intuition. My parents had me study the violin from the time I was six. My new discovery is the result of musical perception.” </p> <br>
            <p id="quote2" class="Einstein"> &mdash; Albert Einstein </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And some of the pertinent css:

```
div #moreinfo {
background-color: #F1F1F1;
/* #d3dfed; original colour */
color: black;
height: 150%;
margin-top: 0%;
/* position: relative; */

}
#moreinfo #benefits-main {
background-color: #d3dfed;
height: 60%;
width: 100%;
}
#benefits-main #top-row { height: 50%; } #benefits-main #bottom-row { height:               50%; }

#benefits-main .benefits-title { margin-top: 2%;}
#benefits-main #leftfact { height: 100%; width: 33%; float: left; background-   color: #b7cbe2; } #benefits-main #leftfact2 { height: 100%; width: 33%; float:  left; 
 background-color: #c5d5e7;  /*background-color: white;*/}
#benefits-main #centrefact { height: 100%; width: 33%; float: left;  background-color: #c5d5e7; /* background-color: white;*/} #benefits-main #centrefact2 {height: 100%; width: 33%; float: left;
background-color: #b7cbe2;}
#benefits-main #rightfact { height: 100%; width: 33%; float: left; background-color: #b7cbe2; /* #e1e9f3; */} #benefits-main #rightfact2 {height: 100%; width: 33%; float: left;
 background-color: #c5d5e7; /* background-color: white;*/ } 
 #button2 {
height: 20%; 
width: 40%; 
background-color: #4a79b1; 
margin-top: 28%;
margin-right: auto; 
margin-left: auto; 
font-weight: 300;}
#button2 p {
font-family: Avenir Next, sans-serif !important;
color: #FFFFFF !important;
font-weight: 200 !important;
padding-top: 7%;
}
.button2text {
color: white;
}
a.rcmlink:link { color: #EEEEEE; } a.rcmlink:visited { color: #EEEEEE; }    a.rcmlink:active {color: #EEEEEE;}
#benefits-main #bodytext {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}


#moreinfo p {
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
color: #22384f;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Montserrat , sans-serif;
}
div #topquote {
background-color: #d3dfed; /* #9bb7d6; */
height: 20%;
}
#topquote #quote {
/* position: absolute; /* top: 5%; */
text-align: center;
}
#topquote #quote2 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Roboto;
bottom: 2%; 
} 
/* #topquote2 { background-color: #d3dfed; height: 10%; } */
div #bottomquote {
text-align: center;
height: 20%;
}

#quote2 {
font-size: 15px;
font-family: Roboto !important;
}

div #musicquote {
 /* position: absolute; bottom: 2.5%; */
}
```

Comment: You want the text to stay fixed? So, that it does not break a line when the window shrinks?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "break a line" but yeah. So it doesn't trespass onto a different div when the window shrinks.

Comment: remove `height:150%`from `#moreinfo` seems to fix..

Comment: still same problem unfortunately on the browser, on jsfiddle it kind've fixes it but messes everything else up lol.

Comment: Line break = trespass

Comment: is that css? and put it in all the divs where text overlaps?

Comment: oh never mind you mean trespass is the same thing as line break. Ok :D

Comment: I think you need to wrap your nav bar in a fixed container. You are using bootstrap so look into some bootstrap components that add a FIXED  style instead of a responsive style to your nav bar. The navbar links are trespassing each other because that is how a responsive navbar should work, which by default bootstrap does.

Comment: ^ I meant the divs in #moreinfo (a bit lower in the page). Nav bar is ok for now. Apologies for not being specific.

Comment: Just to comment on your final edit: it might seem simpler to make a 'computer' version of the site and add on mobile styles later. It isn't. Thinking about the mobile version now and adding in additional styles for bigger screens is absolutely the way to go. I guess you're just starting out at this (kudos!): it's intimidating trying to do everything at once. I would strongly suggest trying to find a template that does most of what you want and using that - then as you get more comfortable you can start adding in custom styling and additional code, moving to something bespoke down the line.

Answer (score 1):

I've pulled out just that row into a stripped down example. The most important CSS is this:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.fact {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
html {
    color: #22384F;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.fact {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #B7CBE2;
}

.fact:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #C5D5E7;
}

.benefits-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Montserrat , sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="fact">
    <p class="benefits-title">  express yourself</p> <br>
    <p> Music is the best way for you to express yourself, unleash your creativity, and get inspired. Immerse yourself or your children in the world of music through musical education to produce an enhanced appreciation and understanding of this art </p>
  </div>
  <div class="fact">
    <p class="benefits-title"> improved cognitive abilities </p> <br>
    <p> The auditory precision required in music study results in dramatic improvements in language abilities. Musically trained children are able to distinguish subtleties of speech, resulting in increased verbal, comprehension, reading, and communication skills. Students of music have better information processing, stronger neural connections, improved memory, and bigger brains in general.
    </p></div>
  <div class="fact">
    <p class="benefits-title"> increased focus and academics</p>
    <p> Music gives its learners an increased attention span and stronger focus as well as self-discpline. Children who learn music have higher IQs and better motor coordination. Studies have found that music students significantly outperform academically compared to other students and are more motivated.
    </p></div> 
</div>
```

Using `display: table-cell` means that each `div` in your row will always have the same height. You want to avoid assigning your HTML elements heights at all unless you really know what you're doing: things can get messy very quickly.

You'll notice I've also changed things up a bit, removing your IDs and replacing them with classes. There's good reason for that: it keeps the specificity of your selectors low, which will make things much easier to maintain in the long run. It also lets you re-use styles and avoid having to come up with unique IDs (such as `#leftfact2`) when they aren't required.

Having the same ID repeated multiple times is also wrong, and will cause headaches if you want the page to validate or - more importantly - start adding JavaScript. I would recommend avoiding the use of IDs for styling altogether (that's somewhat controversial, but [smarter](http://cssguidelin.es/#ids-in-css) [people](http://css-tricks.com/a-line-in-the-sand/) than me say the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Putting heights on divs forces the text to overflow once they are too small to contain the text. If you let the divs height stay auto and controlled spacing around them with padding top/bottom then they would automatically get longer to fit the text as you resize the window.

Not sure if this really answers your question but I'm not exactly sure what you are asking?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will test it out and see if that's what I wanted.

Comment: Ok so height: auto molds the size of the div to the text. However, I'd like all the divs to stay the same size, despite reducing the size of the window.

Comment: You'd have to handle that with media queries or JS. You can either reduce the size of the text or increase the div size once the text is too large to fit.